# Pass variable to a form - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I read the others questions on this topic, but my app still doesn't work :(

Here is my code:

```
class ChooseCatType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $user;

    function __construct(\EM\MyFriendsBundle\Entity\User  $user) 
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


     public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'EMMyFriendsBundle:Category',
            'property' => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function ($repository) use ($user)
                { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('cat')
                                    ->select('cat')
                                    ->where('cat.user', ':user')
                                    ->setParameter('user', $user);
                },
                        ));
    }

    public function getName()
        {
            return 'choose_category';
        }
    }
```

This is in my controller:

```
$cat = new Category();

        $dd_form = $this->createForm(new \EM\MyFriendsBundle\Entity\ChooseCatType($user), $cat);
```

but I get an error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFriends\src\EM\MyFriendsBundle\Entity\ChooseCatType.php line 24
```

which is the line with the use statement. 
There is a difference between my code and the answers to the other related questions that they use a concrete repository, but I think that this shouldn't be the problem. Or it is? Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: excellent question... Helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you all you need to know: you are using a variable which has never been defined ($user). Just add this before the $builder->add line:

```
$user = $this->user;
```